# How to add extra options to CoAP request?

Tags: coap, californium

I know that CoAP defines some options which can be included in the sending request and each option has their own number. The structure of the CoAP uri request looks like:

*coap-URI = "coap:" "//" host [ ":" port ] path-abempty [ "?" query ]*

where inside they include some options like: Uri-Host, Uri-Port, Uri-Path, and Uri-Query, and each of them has their own number, ex: 3 for Uri-Host, 11 for Uri Path.... . And I would like to add some more extra options to this CoAP request, for example some options number 256, 257...How can I do that?

Thank you in advanced

Son

Comment: did you figure out the answer for above question ? if yes please share answer

Comment: tried this request.getOptions().addOption(new Option(256, "admin:admin" )); But receiver Can't see this

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to pass the Option Number 256.

```java
CoapClient client = new CoapClient(...);
Request request = new Request(CoAP.Code.GET, CoAP.Type.NON);
OptionSet optionSet = new OptionSet();
optionSet.addOption(new Option(256, "admin:admin"));
request.setOptions(optionSet);
client.advanced(request); // or async version
client.shutdown();
```

At resource:

```java
@Override
public void handleGET(CoapExchange exchange) {
    OptionSet optionSet = exchange.advanced().getRequest().getOptions();
    List<Option> options = optionSet.asSortedList();
    options.stream()
            .filter(o -> o.getNumber() == 256)
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(o -> System.err.println(o.getNumber() + " " + o.getStringValue()));
}
```

Output:

```
256 admin:admin
```

However, Option Number 256 may not be a proper choice in general:

[RFC 7252 The Constrained Application Protocol (CoAP). 12.2. CoAP Option Numbers Registry](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252#section-12.2)

> The IANA policy for future additions to this sub-registry is split
> into three tiers as follows.  The range of 0..255 is reserved for
> options defined by the IETF (IETF Review or IESG Approval).  The
> range of 256..2047 is reserved for commonly used options with public
> specifications (Specification Required).  The range of 2048..64999 is
> for all other options including private or vendor-specific ones,
> which undergo a Designated Expert review to help ensure that the
> option semantics are defined correctly.  The option numbers between
> 65000 and 65535 inclusive are reserved for experiments.  They are not
> meant for vendor-specific use of any kind and MUST NOT be used in
> operational deployments.